# Azure and GitHub Connections are not well synced

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

While creating a project in Azure DevOps , the repository connection to the GitHub has been pointed.

But if you push any code the GitHub repository, this update is not seen from the Azure DevOps Reps view.

Even the creation of the new branches at GitHub site are not shown in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it doesn't do what you think it does. Connection is not supposed to sync content across repositories. Its "just" being used to connect to the repository on the build agent and pull the sources. If you want to sync repos in Github and Azure Repos you'd need to implement a custom solution. Nothing built-in exists in Azure Repos or Github.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/connect-to-github?view=azure-devops